# Trace method calls with javascript proxy

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, es6-proxy

```js
var handler1 = {
     get:function(target,key){
         if (typeof target[key] == "function"){
             var method = Reflect.get(target, key);
             return method.bind(target);
         }
     }
}
var handler2 = {
    get: function(target, key){
          if (typeof target[key] == "function"){
            return function(...args){
               var method = Reflect.get(target, key);
               return method.apply(target, args);
            }
          }
     }
}
var proxyObject = new Proxy(window, handler1);
window.obj = function(){console.log("function invoked")};
window.obj.prop = 3; 
var o = proxyObject.obj;
o()// prints "function invoked"
console.log(o.prop) // returns undefined
```

Both the handlers intercept method calls just fine, however in the process any property on the method object is lost. Is there a way to bind the correct context and also retain the method properties in the object returned by the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `bind` creates a whole new function that is different from the original:

```js
function foo(a, b) { return a + b; };

var bar = foo.bind({});

console.log(foo === bar);
```

So in your handler, instead of returning a bound function, just return the original one:

```js
var handler = {
    get:function(target,key){
        if (typeof target[key] == "function") {
            return Reflect.get(target, key);                       // return the original function
        }
    }
}

var proxyObject = new Proxy(window, handler);
window.obj = function() { console.log("function invoked"); };
window.obj.prop = 3;

var o = proxyObject.obj;
o()                                                                // prints "function invoked"
console.log(o.prop)                                                // returns 3
console.log(o === window.obj);                                     // true
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, because a lot of functions won't have the correct context while invocation. 
`obj.alert("alert message")` would result in invalid invocation error. We need to set the correct `this` value before returning a function

Comment: @AyushGoel As I said, the binding create a new function. If you really want the bound function to have those properties you could copy them once the binding is done, but I don't think that's good idea: `var boundMethod = ...; Object.assign(boundMethod, originalMethod); return boundMethod;`